# shell script to find first and last occourance of a string

Tags: shell, hadoop

I have prepared a shell script to do the following in a 50 node hadoop cluster:

- list all the log files related to my application in each server
- print the last modified timestamp, hostname, filename
- sort the log files from 50 nodes as per the modified time stamp

current output format is:

```
2016-07-11-01:06 server1 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log.6.gz
2016-07-12-05:23 server1 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log.7.gz
2016-07-13-08:38 server2 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log
2016-07-13-10:38 server3 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log.out
2016-07-13-10:38 server2 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log.err
2016-07-13-10:38 server5 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log
2016-07-15-10:22 server4 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6703.log.out
2016-07-15-10:22 server3 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6703.log.err
2016-07-15-10:22 server2 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6703.log
```

.

```
totallogs=""
for server in $(cat all-hadoop-cluster-servers.txt); do
    logs1="$(ssh user_id@$server 'ls /var/log/hadoop/storm/ -ltr --time-style="+%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M" | grep MY_APPLICATION | awk  -v host=$HOSTNAME "{print \$6, host, \$7}"' )"
    if [ -z "${logs1}"  ]; then
        continue
    else
        logs1+="\n"
        totallogs+=$logs1
    fi  
done
for el in "${totallogs[@]}"
do
    printf "$el"
done | sort
```

How to find the first occurrence of the "**unique-ID**" and last occurrence of the "**unique-ID**" in each log file along with the above output.

Expected output format is:

**time_stamp hostname filename first-unique-ID last-unique-ID**

```
2016-07-11-01:06 server1 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log.6.gz    1467005065878   1467105065877
2016-07-12-05:23 server1 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log.7.gz    1467105065878   1467205065860
2016-07-13-08:38 server2 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log         1467205065861   1467305065852
2016-07-13-10:38 server3 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log.out     
2016-07-13-10:38 server2 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log.err     
2016-07-13-10:38 server5 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6701.log         1467305065853   1467405065844
2016-07-15-10:22 server4 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6703.log.out     
2016-07-15-10:22 server3 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6703.log.err     
2016-07-15-10:22 server2 MY_APPLICATION-worker-6703.log         1467405065845   1467505065853
```

Sample log file:

```
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | unique-ID >>>>>> 1467205065861
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,817 | DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java | 86 | Loading bean definitions
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java | 185 | Loaded 5 bean definitions from location pattern [samContext.xml]
INFO | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java | 323 | Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [tmfContext.xml]
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | DefaultDocumentLoader.java | 72 | Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | BeansDtdResolver.java | 72 | Found beans DTD [http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd] in classpath: spring-beans.dtd
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,848 | unique-ID >>>>>> 1467205065862
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:44,864 | DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java | 86 | Loading bean definitions
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 411 | Finished creating instance of bean 'MS-SQL'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java | 213 | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'MySQL'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 383 | Creating instance of bean 'MySQL'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 459 | Eagerly caching bean 'MySQL' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 411 | Finished creating instance of bean 'MySQL'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java | 213 | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'Oracle'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 383 | Creating instance of bean 'Oracle'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,458 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 459 | Eagerly caching bean 'Oracle' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,473 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 411 | Finished creating instance of bean 'Oracle'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,473 | DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java | 213 | Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'PostgreSQL'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,473 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 383 | Creating instance of bean 'PostgreSQL'
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,473 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 459 | Eagerly caching bean 'PostgreSQL' to allow for resolving potential circular references
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,473 | AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java | 411 | Finished creating instance of bean 'PostgreSQL'
INFO | 2008-09-06 10:51:45,473 | SQLErrorCodesFactory.java | 128 | SQLErrorCodes loaded: [DB2, Derby, H2, HSQL, Informix, MS-SQL, MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, Sybase]
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:52:44,817 | DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java | 86 | Loading bean definitions
DEBUG | 2008-09-06 10:52:44,848 | unique-ID >>>>>> 1467205065864
```

Comment: You should show us a representative sample of your input along with the corresponding desired output. Note that you should never read lines using `for` (use `while read -r` instead).

Comment: @anubhava, that is a mock log file. text "unique-ID >>>>>>" will be there in log file for every few statements. the value next to the text "unique-ID >>>>>>"  is the unique-ID mentioned in the expected output.

Comment: Yes but in order to build a solution we need to have an expected output that can be generated from the given sample input. eg. `1467305065852` in output is not even present in sample input.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep 'uniqueID' sample_log_file | sed -n '1p;$p'
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using `awk`, you could change your `awk` program

```
"{print \$6, host, \$7}"
```

to

```
"{ first=last=\"\"; path=\"/var/log/hadoop/storm/\"\$7; while (getline var <path) if (split(var, arr, \">>>>>>\") > 1) { if (!first) first=arr[2]; last=arr[2] } print \$6, host, \$7, \"\t\", first, last }"
```

in order to let it do the work.